# Radio button global state for name attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to be able to have radion buttons or checkboxes to show / hide content if its checked. There will be more radio buttons and checkboxes to show content in the same form, so to distinguish them from each other, it could be based on the name attribute.

So far i can show the hidden fields when i check the radio buttons, but i want one to cancel out the other, but only if it has the same name attribute (something else can also work).

Is there a react genius who can figure this out? I would be forever in your debt :)

```
class PartnerRoute extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showOneTimeFee: '',
            showSubscription: ''
        };
    }

    toggleOneTimeFee = () => {
        const currentState = this.state.showOneTimeFee;
        this.setState({
            showOneTimeFee: !currentState
        })
    }
    toggleSubscription = () => {
        const currentState = this.state.showSubscription;
        this.setState({
            showSubscription: !currentState
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="partner-route">
                <ContentContainer>                    
                    <div className="form--create-event">
                        <form>
                            <h3>Event information</h3>
                            <GridContainer columnCount="one">
                                <CustomInput type="text" placeholder="Event name" />                              
                            </GridContainer>

                            <GridContainer columnCount="one">
                                <CustomTextarea type="text" placeholder="Event description" />  
                            </GridContainer>   

                            <h3>Event date</h3>
                            <GridContainer columnCount="three">
                                <CustomInput type="text" placeholder="Day" />
                                <CustomInput type="text" placeholder="Month" /> 
                                <CustomInput type="text" placeholder="Year" />
                            </GridContainer> 

                            <h3>Payment</h3>
                            <GridContainer columnCount="one">
                                <CustomRadio 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="payment" 
                                    id="rb1" 
                                    value="1"
                                    label="Free, no payment needed" 
                                />
                                <CustomRadio 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="payment" 
                                    id="rb2" 
                                    value="2"
                                    label="1 time fee"
                                    onChange={this.toggleOneTimeFee} 
                                />
                                {this.state.showOneTimeFee &&
                                    <div className="hidden-field">
                                        <CustomInput type="text" placeholder="Price" />
                                    </div>
                                }

                                <CustomRadio 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="payment" 
                                    id="rb3" 
                                    value="3"
                                    label="Subscription"
                                    onChange={this.toggleSubscription}
                                />
                                {this.state.showSubscription &&
                                    <div className="hidden-field">
                                        <CustomInput type="text" placeholder="Price" />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </GridContainer> 
                        </form>   
                    </div>
                </ContentContainer>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PartnerRoute
```

Comment: I am not getting your requirement

Comment: I have edited my explanation further. Let me know if you still dont get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example where I used `setState` with `prevState` that is important and also I used `changeHandler` for all three radio. Moreover, to run this code in my side I changed all Custom input with generic input for ex `CustomInput` to `input`. Please revert this your side.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class PartnerRoute extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showOneTimeFee: false,
            showSubscription: false
        };
    }
    handleChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.value == 2) // One Time Fee
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    showOneTimeFee: !prevState.showOneTimeFee,
                    showSubscription: false
                };
            });
        else if (event.target.value == 3) // Subscription
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    showOneTimeFee: false,
                    showSubscription: !prevState.showSubscription
                };
            });
        else // Free, no payment needed
            this.setState({
                showOneTimeFee: false,
                showSubscription: false
            });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="partner-route">
                <div>
                    <div className="form--create-event">
                        <form>
                            <h3>Event information</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Event name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" multiline="true" placeholder="Event description"/>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Event date</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Day"/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Month"/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Year"/>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Payment</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment" id="rb1" value="1" label="Free, no payment needed"
                                       onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                <label htmlFor="rb1">Free, no payment needed</label><br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment" id="rb2" value="2" label="1 time fee"
                                       onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                <label htmlFor="rb2">1 time fee</label><br/>
                                {this.state.showOneTimeFee &&
                                <div className="hidden-field">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="One Time Price"/>
                                </div>
                                }
                                <input type="radio" name="payment" id="rb3" value="3" label="Subscription"
                                       onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                <label htmlFor="rb3">Subscription</label><br/>
                                {this.state.showSubscription &&
                                <div className="hidden-field">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Subscription Price"/>
                                </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: When i implement your solution it works, but as soon as i change the input to my CustomRadio it no longer works. Its like the value is empty?

Comment: I can use ID i just dont understand why value is empty. Any idea? Thanks anyway - its great.

Comment: Hi, without seeing `CustomRadio` it is very hard to tell. is your problem solved?

Comment: I made a spelling error in the value field ... Thanks for all your help Khabir.